# Replicating a bond

Tags: interest-rates, bond, risk-neutral-measure, hedging, replication

In Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance Volume II*, section 6.5, page 273, Shreve talks about pricing a zero-coupon bond.

> A zero-coupon bond is a contract promising to pay a certain "face"
> amound, which we take to be $1$, at a fixed maturity date $T$. Prior
> to that, the bond makes no payments. The risk-neutral pricing formula
> (5.2.30) says that the discounted price of this bond should be a
> martingale under the risk-neutral measure. In other words, for $0\leq
> > t \leq T$, the price of the bond $B(t, T)$ should satisfy
>
> $$D(t)B(t, T) = \widetilde{\mathbb{E}}[D(t) |
> > \mathcal{F}(t)]\text{.}\tag{6.5.2}$$
>
> (Note that $B(T, T)=1$.) This gives us the zero-coupon bond pricing
> formula
>
> $$D(t)B(t, T) = \widetilde{\mathbb{E}}[e^{-\int_t^T R(s) \mathrm{d}s}
> > | \mathcal{F}(t)]\text{,}\tag{6.5.3}$$
>
> which we take as a definition.

The justification for equation (5.2.30) was based on a replication strategy. The price of the option comes from creating a portfolio process $X(t)$ that **trades in the underlying stock and money market** to replicate the option value $V(t)$.

> $$D(t)V(t) = \widetilde{\mathbb{E}}[D(T)V(T) | \mathcal{F}(t)], 0\leq
> > t \leq T\text{.}\tag{5.2.30}$$

So I have two versions of my question:

1. What replication strategy is implied in Shreve's book by taking definition (6.5.3)? Are we assuming that there is a riskless money market?
2. If Shreve's book does not imply a replication strategy, what are the simple replication strategies used in practice? (perhaps ignoring complicated details like credit rating and foreign money markets)

Comment: The textbook uses "bond" and "money market" inerchangeably. You can invest (or borrow) $\$1$ risk-free now, and receive (or pay) exactly $\$1+r$ later.

Comment: @DimitriVulis I'm fairly certain there are portfolios with lower risk and higher returns than bonds. "Bonds" and "money market" are not interchangeable. If you want to replicate a bond, you need some financial instrument besides the bond.

Comment: Right. Also markets are often not complete. Most quotes have bid-ask spread.. The interest you'd pay for a loan is higher than the interest you'd earn for holding T-bills.  A textbook assumes away a lot of real-life complexity so it can explain basic ideas more clearly.

Comment: Yes, we are *assuming* a money market where one can lend and also *borrow* (!) risk free for short periods of time dt at a constantly changing risk-free rate. And bonds with longer maturities $\Delta t$ have to compete with these money market loans to avoid arbitrage. So the money market is at the core and bonds are built on top of that. An elegant if somewhat unrealistic structure.